# how to handle file extension correctly in SAF (Storage access framework)?

Tags: android

So I'm saving an image to device with this code:

```
        Intent intentSaveToDevice = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT)
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        .setType("image/*")
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, model.StuffName);

        startActivityForResult(intentSaveToDevice, StuffdApp.REQUEST_CODE_SAVE_SAF);
```

And it works fine, but the image saves without the `*.jpg` or `*.png` extension.

So I tried this:

```
.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, model.StuffName+".jpg");
```

And that seems to work fine. Except for when there is a duplicate file, I get this:

`mysavedimage.jpg(1)` instead of `mysavedimage(1).jpg`

(1) is appended by the SAF automatically, but in the wrong place. Tried on android 4.4 and 5.

Also tried changing `.setType("image/*")` to different jpg variations, but that did not help.

What's the proper way of handling file extensions in SAF? Specifically, how does one get the correct extension when saving a duplicate file?

Comment: Still question is not clear, Can you please tell what exactly you want your output as ?

Comment: Roths, can you go with the first approach and check in onActivityResults , uri that you are getting has what mime type set ?  and I guess if your are getting the correct mime type then setting the file extension is not a big problem

Comment: I know this is just work around ! why this happening is seriously a issue. I think we should report it google to fix it. Ideally SAF should take care of all this

Comment: 4 years later, this is still a problem, but now we are forced to use SAF... Did you report the bug to Google?

Comment: Did not report it

Comment: The funny fact is that if you choose `png`, the name *will be* `mysavedimage (1).png`!

Comment: apparently, `.setType("image/png")` triggers special treatment: if you type the file name `mysavedimage.jpg`, the resulting file will be `mysavedimage.jpg.png`!

Comment: The reason is that some MIME type are registered, others not, for example:

MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().hasMimeType("application/xml") and MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().hasMimeType("image/jpg") are not registered , but

MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().hasMimeType("text/plain") and MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().hasMimeType("image/png") are registered .

 "mime-support" package from Google : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/mime-support/+/fa3f892f28db393b1411f046877ee48179f6a4cf/mime.types